# modifying the output of a SP

Tags: sql-server

In my SQl server Sp.

```
`SELECT rating as [Rating],count(id) as [RatingCount]
FROM MMBPollResults
where mmb_id = @MMbid
GROUP BY rating 

This SP returns the rating for each user.
i:e rating    ratingcount
`    1           2
     2           1
     5           4
```

So this means that

```
2users have rated the transaction with 1star
1 user has rated the transaction with 2stars
4 users have rated the transaction with 5stars
```

This is how I need the output

```
rating    ratingcount
`    1           2
     2           1
     3           0
     4           0
     5           4
```

Sorry, if this is a silly question
Thanks
Sun

Comment: what does the data in MMBPollResults look like?  Do you have a lookup table with all of the possible ratings somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a table with 1 to 5. This could be a number table or some other rating table.

Here I use a simple UNION to make a table with 1 to 5

```
SELECT 
    List.Rating,
    count(MMB.*) as [RatingCount]
FROM
    (
    SELECT 1 AS Rating
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
    ) List
    LEFT JOIN
    MMBPollResults MMB ON List.Rating = MMB.Rating AND MMB.mmb_id = @MMbid
GROUP BY
    List.Rating 
ORDER BY
    List.Rating;
```